# Google site can not access correctly external url

Tags: google-sites, external-url

I want to add an external URL on my google site, and I can add and access URL link in "preview" mode  where the format of the link address is https://www.google.com/url?q=myurl

However, when the webpage is published, the link address will become https://sites.google.com/view/username/myurl and cannot be accessed resulting in a 404 error.

Is there a way to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Google corrected this issue recently, now it works fine. The question is closed.